# Postgresql: UNION ALL is slower than UNION when creating table?

Tags: postgresql, union, common-table-expression

I have one `UNION` query. From the EXPLAIN output, I noticed that UNION always do a sort after append. So I changed it to `UNION ALL`.

Supposedly the query should be faster ?
But the actual execution show that with `UNION ALL` the query always return seconds later. (maybe my data set is not big enough, the difference looks marginal, but I still doesn't make sense to me.) Did I miss anything ?

QUERY

```
WITH wcal AS (...), wlog AS (...)
SELECT * INTO temp.utlog FROM (
    SELECT * FROM wcal 
    UNION SELECT * FROM wlog
) as t2;
```

EXPLAIN UNION

```
QUERY PLAN
Unique  (cost=691313.04..737080.66 rows=3051175 width=80)
  CTE wcal
  CTE wlog
  ->  Sort  (cost=691313.04..698940.98 rows=3051175 width=80)
        Sort Key: wcal.wts, wcal.wdate, wcal.wstate, wcal.wln, wcal.wid
        ->  Append  (cost=0.00..91535.25 rows=3051175 width=80)
              ->  CTE Scan on wcal  (cost=0.00..52600.00 rows=2630000 width=60)
              ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 2"  (cost=0.00..12635.25 rows=421175 width=64)
                    ->  CTE Scan on wlog  (cost=0.00..8423.50 rows=421175 width=64)
```

EXPLAIN UNION ALL

```
QUERY PLAN
Append  (cost=0.00..91535.25 rows=3051175 width=80)
  CTE wcal ...
  CTE wlog ...
  ->  CTE Scan on wcal  (cost=0.00..52600.00 rows=2630000 width=60)
  ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 2"  (cost=0.00..12635.25 rows=421175 width=64)
        ->  CTE Scan on wlog  (cost=0.00..8423.50 rows=421175 width=64)
```

Actual results;

**with `UNION`**

```
Table temp.utlog dropped

Execution time: 0.02s
Statement 1 of 5 finished

0 rows affected
WITH executed successfully

Execution time: 6.05s
Statement 2 of 5 finished
```

**with `UNION ALL`**

```
Table temp.utlog1 dropped

Execution time: 0.02s
Statement 1 of 5 finished

0 rows affected
WITH executed successfully

Execution time: 6.81s
Statement 2 of 5 finished
```

**Results Counts in new table are the same...**

```
SELECT count(*) FROM temp.utlog1
UNION ALL
SELECT count(*) FROM temp.utlog

count
364414
364414
```

**`EXPLAIN ANALYZE` `UNION ALL`**

```
QUERY PLAN
Append  (cost=0.00..11658.36 rows=388612 width=80) (actual time=0.670..3382.220 rows=364414 loops=1)
  CTE wcal ...
  CTE wlog ...
  ->  CTE Scan on wcal  (cost=0.00..720.00 rows=36000 width=60) (actual time=0.668..140.251 rows=33624 loops=1)
  ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 2"  (cost=0.00..10578.36 rows=352612 width=64) (actual time=2635.901..3179.006 rows=330790 loops=1)
        ->  CTE Scan on wlog  (cost=0.00..7052.24 rows=352612 width=64) (actual time=2635.897..3043.421 rows=330790 loops=1)
Planning time: 1.759 ms
Execution time: 6570.793 ms
...
Planning time: 1.713 ms
Execution time: 5883.275 ms
...
Planning time: 1.351 ms
Execution time: 7092.713 ms
...
Planning time: 1.318 ms
Execution time: 5803.567 ms
```

**`EXPLAIN ANALYZE` `UNION`**

```
QUERY PLAN
Unique  (cost=65006.04..70835.22 rows=388612 width=80) (actual time=4259.243..4534.226 rows=364414 loops=1)
  CTE wcal ...
  CTE wlog ...
  ->  Sort  (cost=65006.04..65977.57 rows=388612 width=80) (actual time=4259.239..4370.691 rows=364414 loops=1)
        Sort Key: wcal.wts, wcal.wdate, wcal.wstate, wcal.wln, wcal.wid
        Sort Method: external sort  Disk: 11832kB
        ->  Append  (cost=0.00..11658.36 rows=388612 width=80) (actual time=0.677..3486.529 rows=364414 loops=1)
              ->  CTE Scan on wcal  (cost=0.00..720.00 rows=36000 width=60) (actual time=0.676..120.320 rows=33624 loops=1)
              ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 2"  (cost=0.00..10578.36 rows=352612 width=64) (actual time=2760.279..3309.084 rows=330790 loops=1)
                    ->  CTE Scan on wlog  (cost=0.00..7052.24 rows=352612 width=64) (actual time=2760.275..3189.444 rows=330790 loops=1)
Planning time: 1.500 ms
Execution time: 7577.380 ms
...
Planning time: 1.375 ms
Execution time: 6777.699 ms
...
Planning time: 1.375 ms
Execution time: 6777.699 ms
...
Planning time: 1.340 ms
Execution time: 6964.954 ms
```

**`UNION` (0._s) and `UNION ALL`(4._s) without `SELECT INTO`**

```
WITH executed successfully

Execution time: 0.41s
Statement 1 of 4 finished

WITH executed successfully

Execution time: 0.28s
Statement 1 of 4 finished

WITH executed successfully

Execution time: 0.33s
Statement 1 of 4 finished

WITH executed successfully

Execution time: 0.25s
Statement 1 of 4 finished

WITH executed successfully

Execution time: 0.28s
Statement 1 of 5 finished

WITH executed successfully

Execution time: 4.67s
Statement 1 of 5 finished

WITH executed successfully

Execution time: 4.17s
Statement 1 of 5 finished

WITH executed successfully

Execution time: 4.17s
Statement 1 of 5 finished

WITH executed successfully

Execution time: 4.33s
Statement 1 of 5 finished
```

**`UNION` without `CTE`**

```
QUERY PLAN
Unique  (cost=699529.52..752925.08 rows=3051175 width=65) (actual time=3041.962..3488.246 rows=364414 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=699529.52..707157.46 rows=3051175 width=65) (actual time=3041.958..3296.505 rows=364414 loops=1)
        Sort Key: s1.s1, ((date_trunc('day'::text, s1.s1))::date), (NULL::character varying(3)), s2.wline, (NULL::boolean), (NULL::integer)
        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 12544kB
        ->  Append  (cost=0.00..120611.73 rows=3051175 width=65) (actual time=0.729..2218.973 rows=364414 loops=1)
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..46077.88 rows=2630000 width=36) (actual time=0.727..94.359 rows=33624 loops=1)
              ...
              ->  WindowAgg  (cost=198.08..44022.11 rows=421175 width=24) (actual time=0.737..2049.979 rows=330790 loops=1)
              ...

Planning time: 1.318 ms
Execution time: 6438.852 ms
```

**`UNION` with `CTE`**

```
QUERY PLAN
Unique  (cost=670453.04..723848.60 rows=3051175 width=65) (actual time=3726.279..3973.870 rows=364414 loops=1)
  CTE wcal
    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..46077.88 rows=2630000 width=36) (actual time=1.788..82.337 rows=33624 loops=1)
    ...
  CTE wlog
    ->  Sort  (cost=92006.40..93059.34 rows=421175 width=24) (actual time=2542.472..2743.255 rows=330790 loops=1)
          Sort Key: tbl_line_evts.evt_time
          Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 11712kB
          ->  WindowAgg  (cost=198.08..44022.11 rows=421175 width=24) (actual time=0.932..1982.497 rows=330790 loops=1)
          ...
  ->  Sort  (cost=670453.04..678080.98 rows=3051175 width=65) (actual time=3726.275..3823.236 rows=364414 loops=1)
        Sort Key: wcal.wts, wcal.wdate, wcal.wstate, wcal.wln, wcal.wdirty, wcal.wid
        Sort Method: external sort  Disk: 12584kB
        ->  Append  (cost=0.00..91535.25 rows=3051175 width=65) (actual time=1.800..3082.954 rows=364414 loops=1)
              ->  CTE Scan on wcal  (cost=0.00..52600.00 rows=2630000 width=57) (actual time=1.798..125.699 rows=33624 loops=1)
              ->  CTE Scan on wlog  (cost=0.00..8423.50 rows=421175 width=49) (actual time=2542.476..2915.524 rows=330790 loops=1)
Planning time: 2.381 ms
Execution time: 5950.324 ms
```

**`UNION ALL` without `CTE`**

```
QUERY PLAN
Sort  (cost=721442.46..729070.40 rows=3051175 width=80) (actual time=3416.176..3627.253 rows=364414 loops=1)
  Sort Key: s1.s1
  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 11816kB
  ->  Append  (cost=0.00..121664.67 rows=3051175 width=80) (actual time=0.675..2726.980 rows=364414 loops=1)
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..46077.88 rows=2630000 width=39) (actual time=0.674..118.694 rows=33624 loops=1)
        ...
        ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 2"  (cost=198.08..49286.79 rows=421175 width=51) (actual time=1.223..2517.292 rows=330790 loops=1)
              ->  WindowAgg  (cost=198.08..45075.04 rows=421175 width=51) (actual time=1.218..2334.702 rows=330790 loops=1)
                ...
Planning time: 1.360 ms
Execution time: 5795.449 ms
```

**`UNION ALL` with `CTE`**

```
QUERY PLAN
Append  (cost=0.00..91535.25 rows=3051175 width=80) (actual time=0.718..3595.377 rows=364414 loops=1)
  CTE wcal
    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..46077.88 rows=2630000 width=39) (actual time=0.709..86.700 rows=33624 loops=1)
    ...
  CTE wlog
    ->  Sort  (cost=98820.34..99873.28 rows=421175 width=51) (actual time=2818.220..3049.432 rows=330790 loops=1)
          Sort Key: tbl_line_evts.evt_time
          Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 10952kB
          ->  WindowAgg  (cost=198.08..45075.04 rows=421175 width=51) (actual time=0.884..2224.477 rows=330790 loops=1)
            ...
  ->  CTE Scan on wcal  (cost=0.00..52600.00 rows=2630000 width=60) (actual time=0.716..129.933 rows=33624 loops=1)
  ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 2"  (cost=0.00..12635.25 rows=421175 width=64) (actual time=2818.229..3400.468 rows=330790 loops=1)
        ->  CTE Scan on wlog  (cost=0.00..8423.50 rows=421175 width=64) (actual time=2818.224..3250.670 rows=330790 loops=1)
Planning time: 2.415 ms
Execution time: 6223.041 ms
```

Comment: Does the `UNION` reduce the size of the returned set? I.e, are there duplicates? Also, the ordering may have an effect on index construction during the INSERT.

Comment: Negative, they yielded same number of records. About the index could you elaborate ?

Comment: When inserting data into an index, it's usually faster if you insert in the order of the index rather than a different or random order, due to I/O, especially on rotating discs (as opposed to SSDs). In your query times without insertion, which Ines are UNION and which are UNION ALL?

Comment: If possible, try replacing the CTEs by subqueries.This will give the planner more freedom.

Comment: Records <1s are for `UNION ALL`, ~4s are for `UNION`. this conforms  to the book well. Its just when I do `SELECT INTO` (without ANALYZE), the results are repeatably the opposite (though margin is small)...

Comment: I tried to remove the CTEs. It didn't seem to change the plan much (kind of good news to me, I really don't like how to query looks like now). Time is most of the time marginally shorter, not sure exactly why.

Comment: Note: your `UNION ALL without CTE`entry has a sort node. I think you swapped some entries.

Comment: Both version sort, I am not sure why the planner decided to sort after append for the sub-query version.  with or w/o  an  `ORDER BY wts ASC` to the end of `) as t2` the `EXPLAIN` output is the same for the sub-query version.

Answer (score 0):

your assumption reconciles [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-union.html)

> UNION...eliminates duplicate rows from its result, in the same way as
>   DISTINCT, unless UNION ALL is used.

(...) mine

If you check the cost of both queries, you find that UNION ALL costs much less. 91K vs 737K. Now to explain difference with real result, I'd suppose that it was a result of io cache and write operations, try measuring time without creating table, but just running 10 explain analyze with `UNION` and then 10 times with `UNION ALL`. Should be less surprising.

Comment: I updated the results. You are right the without table creation, the difference is significant, with ANALYZE, the results are shaky. but without ANALYZE the wired result is still repeatable. So what should I learn ? Should I prefer `UNION` to `UNION ALL` when creating io heavy tables ?

Comment: `explain analyze` actually performs query, while just `explain` only estimates it. You should use `union all` when you want a fast union without `DISTINCT`, and `union` if you want much slower but only distinct rows...

Comment: thanks. I think I get it. in my case, the `union all` returns results ~14x faster than `union` if there is any inefficiency in cache, a 1s difference is not really that bad. `analyze` introduced more delays/breaks, maybe mitigated the intensity, so the results many times looks better than bare query though its unstable.